# How to catch a custom event with Interactivity.EventTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, eventtrigger

I'm trying to catch my custom event (TextUpdateEvent) with Interactivity.EventTrigger in the way shown below. But this code gives rise to System.ArgumentException with the message that "The event "MyTextBox" was not found in the type "tool:MyTextBox.TextUpdateEvent"." Could you tell me what is wrong with this?

```
<UserControl x:Class="mynamespace.MyControl"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mynamespace"
xmlns:info="clr-namespace:mynamespace.info"
xmlns:tool="clr-namespace:mynamespace.tool"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"> 
<Grid>
    <Border>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" Name="itemsControl">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                         
                <DataTemplate DataType="info:MyInfo">                             
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                  
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyComment}"/>
                        <tool:MyTextBox Text="{Binding MyName}" x:Name="myTextBox">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="tool:MyTextBox.TextUpdateEvent"
                                                SourceObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type tool:MyTextBox}}}"
                                                SourceName="myTextBox">                         
                                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="UpdateMyInfo" TargetObject="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </tool:MyTextBox>
                    </StackPanel>                              
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>     
</Grid>
```

```
namespace mynamespace.tool
{
    //used to judge whether or not the update suceeded
    public delegate bool MyTextBoxUpdateHandler(object sender);

    public partial class MyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public MyTextBoxUpdateHandler TextUpdateEvent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Or, do I need to create a custom trigger to catch my custom event?

```
public class TextUpdateEventTrigger : EventTriggerBase<MyTextBox>
{
    // I don't know what I should do here,
    // since the event I'd like to catch is not a RoutedEvent.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `TextUpdateEvent` to an event instead of a property.

```
public event MyTextBoxUpdateHandler TextUpdateEvent;
```

Since you're calling a method in code-behind you also do not need to attach `Interaction` triggers:

```
<tool:MyTextBox 
    x:Name="myTextBox" 
    Text="{Binding MyName}" 
    TextUpdateEvent="UpdateMyInfo" />
```

The `DataContext` Property does not need to be bound on the `UserControl` itself, because it's already a partial class of the `UserControl`, you can remove that too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried this, but TextUpdateEvent was not caught, although there were no exceptions.

Comment: Oooh haha, I did not see the issue in the partial class. You didn't define `TextUpdateEvent` as event, but as a property. I'll change my answer

Comment: Or wait... not thinking straight, let me think about it.

Comment: Yes, I think if you change the `TextUpdateEvent` to an event, it should call the `UpdateMyInfo(object sender)` method in your code behind. As long as you raise the event, of course.

Comment: Thank you again for your care, but in the project I'm engaged in now, TextUpdateEvent must be a property, since it is used in a way like this in XAML. <tool:MyTextBox TextUpdateEvent="SomeEvent"/>

Comment: But to what purpose? If you define `TextUpdateEvent` as an event instead of a property, you are still able to apply `SomeEvent` assuming it conforms with the `MyTextBoxUpdateHandler` delegate.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was lacking in accuracy. I'd like to set a method to MyTextbox, just like <tool:MyTextBox TextUpdateEvent="SomeMethod"/> in xaml, and private bool SomeMethod(object sender) in xaml.cs. Anywhere other than the part I'm in charge of now, MyTextBox is used in this way, and this convention should not be changed. Is it still possible to keep this style unchanged even if the property is replaced with an event?

Comment: Yes, that actually makes the entire `Interaction` part redundant.